# Android: CardView Button can't set background color

Tags: android, button, material-design, android-cardview

I'm using this tutorial
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-login-screen-using-textinputlayout--cms-24168

to try and create a raised button using a CardView and a TextView. It kind of works, but there's an issue.

[image]

The goal is for the whole button to have the teal color, which is my colorPrimary. However you can see only my TextView has that color and that's because I manually set it.

Here's my layout:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/card_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                    card_view:cardElevation="1dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="@string/login"
                            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorTextIcons"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I'm not sure why these lines aren't working:

```
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
```

Comment: Why are you using CardView for creating a Button. Just use Button view.

Comment: @Sharj I'm trying to get ripple effect and a colored background. I've tried using a button but if I give it a background color I can't also give it ripple effect.

Comment: Do you want to change the color of Button and keep it's ripple effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the color of your button using `colorButtonNormal` attribute instead of changing `background` attribute of the button to make it work. 
You can do this using style like this:

```
<Button  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:theme="@style/YourColorButton"/>
```

In your styles.xml

```
<style name="YourColorButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">  
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/yourButtonColorHere</item>
</style>
```

Make sure you are using latest version of `appcompat` support library.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the background atribute to the RelativeLayout tag rather than to CardView tag:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary" >
```

So your code after the corrections should be:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="1dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:singleLine="true"
           android:text="@string/login"
           android:textColor="@color/colorTextIcons"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

You may also want to move the 'foreground' atribute accordingly